# Como integrar spring batch+spring boot+quartz

Tags: java, spring-boot

Bom dia.
Atualmente em meu projeto estou utilizando spring boot e spring batch.
Criar o batch foi fácil, até mesmo executá-lo ao iniciar a aplicação com o tomcat embebed do spring boot porém, preciso executar esse batch de tempos em tempos.
A solução que me vem a mente é utilizar o quartz pra executar esse batch, porém não estou obtendo sucesso com essa integração..
Alguém pode me ajudar com algum exemplo?

Comment: A resposta te ajudou? Faltou alguma informação adicional?

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a anotação `@Scheduled` do Spring.

Crie a classe para executar a tarefa agendada:

```
@Service
public class AgendadorService {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void executaBatch() {
        //Implementar chamada para o batch
    }

}
```

Neste caso a tarefa executa a cada 5 segundos, mas existem outras alterativas para agendamento, conforme a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled).

Para habilitar o recurso de agendamento no Spring Boot, é necessário adicionar a anotação `@EnableScheduling`, conforme segue:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! O único inconveniente é que neste caso eu não consigo parametrizar o fixedRate = 5000, desta forma o tempo fica hardcode.
Como faço pro fixrate ficar parametrizavel?

Comment: Pode colocar num properties e acessar desta forma: (fixedRate = ${api.cron})